# Testing overridden Devise controllers – "No route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I ran `rails g devise:controllers users` and my routes look like

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'sessions'
}
```

I have a `app/controllers/users/sessions_controller` that I want to test. My routes look like:

```
$ rake routes
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       sessions#create
```

I set up my test like this:

```
# test/controllers/users/sessions_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests Users::SessionsController

  test "sign in sanity check" do
    user = users(:one)
    post :create, email: user.email, password: 'password'
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Which fails with the error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/sessions", :email=>"one@example.com", :password=>"password"}
```

How do I correctly POST to the URL I want? I've tried all sorts of variations, but I'm missing some magic sauce here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes.rb to

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions'
}
```

And in your test, make sure you have

```
class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests Users::SessionsController
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  test "sign in sanity check" do
    request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = users(:one)
    post :create, email: user.email, password: 'password'
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

(You can [see how Devise itself does it](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb) for an example.)